# How to add datawarehouse project in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio

how to add data ware house project in VS2015. If I am creating a new project means I will have only one option SQL server database project. so I need to add any add-on . can you please help me.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download [Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) and Install it.

Then Go to File->New->Project->Integration Services and create a new project.